# Paypal form non Encrypted

Tags: php, html, encryption, paypal

I remember when I previously creates a button in Paypal, it gives me a standard format of HTML form, but now all is encrypted. Is there a way to get unencrypted format ?

Because I need to change the amount of price manually by jQuery. Meanwhile, is it safe to do that in website ? Thanks

The encrypted version is like this :

[image]

Comment: can you show us the new form?

Comment: ok, I've updated my post with picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old form API is still supported by PayPal, but they don't offer it as an option when you want to set up a new payment button. If you have an old form already, you can carefully adapt it to work for your new scenario.

The reason PayPal are pushing people off of the form is because the user can easily edit the price, just as you are doing using JavaScript, or using one of the many browser debugging tools available these days. This means it is really easy for someone to edit the price to a lower amount, or adjust one of the other fields in the form before submitting it.

If you want to be able to charge different amounts, you may want to look at the PayPal API instead, which lets you set things up server-side, where there is no danger of simple HTML editing.

Comment: by using paypal API , should I use the express check out ? or is there any other easy method there ?

Comment: Sadly, the new way is harder to implement, but it is more secure. Express check out should do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the simplest way is to hit section 2 on the button creator. At the top it says something along the lines of "save this button at paypal". Un-check that and then when you get to the page which displays your code press "remove code protection". Simple as that.